# Multithreading nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, parallel-processing

I am using Python3.10, and I have a 3 level nested big dictionary in the below format:

```
 a  = {k1:
         {k2:
            {k3:
            }
         }
      }
```

I am supposed to do some tasks on each level. Task is slicing nested dictionary to different files by assigning key values of dictionary as it's name.

- First level names --> f"{k1}.txt"
- Second level names --> f"{k1}{k2}.txt"
- Third level names --> f"{k1}{k2}{k3}.txt"

It is something like below:

```
import pickle

for k1, k1_data in a.items():

   # Save k1_data as f"{k1}.txt" 
   with open(f"{k1}.txt", "wb") as file:
       pickle.dump(k1_data, file)

    for k2, k2_data in k1_data.items():

        # Save k2_data as f"{k1}_{k2}.txt"
        with open(f"{k1}_{k2}.txt", "wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(k2_data, file)

        for k3, k3_data in k2_data.items():

           # Save k3_data as f"{k1}_{k2}_{k3}.txt"
           with open(f"{k1}_{k2}_{k3}.txt", "wb") as file:
               pickle.dump(k3_data, file)
```

It takes 1hour to finish all task. I searched multithreading modules and examples a lot.

They are in the form of collecting and sending parameters to function. Then, they all run in parallel.

In the below example: function --> do_task, parameters --> my_list

```
 result_list = []
 with Pool() as pool:
            for result in pool.map_async(do_task, my_list).get():
                result_list.append(result)
```

However, I am confused how can I do the same thing to my case in Python?

Comment: Thanks for the warning. There was a copy-paste error. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `concurrent.futures` module. It provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables (functions or methods) using threads or processes. It simplifies the process of parallel and concurrent programming by abstracting away the low-level details of thread or process management. [read more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

import it like,

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

and then use it like,

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        
        for k1, k1_data in a.items():
            filename_k1 = f"{k1}.txt"
            futures.append(executor.submit(save_data, filename_k1, k1_data))

            for k2, k2_data in k1_data.items():
                filename_k2 = f"{k1}_{k2}.txt"
                futures.append(executor.submit(save_data, filename_k2, k2_data))

                for k3, k3_data in k2_data.items():
                    filename_k3 = f"{k1}_{k2}_{k3}.txt"
                    futures.append(executor.submit(save_data, filename_k3, k3_data))
        
        # wait here for all tasks to complete
        for future in futures:
            future.result()
```